# Flutter and Android release aab 'android:exported = true' not working

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, google-play-console, flutter-release

I tried to upload the AAB file to the play console but giving the uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without '`android:exported`' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported error. I set the `exported= true` property to the activity too. And also add the `android:exported="true" tools:node="merge"`.

[image]

I made the changes in the manifest as per suggestions then also getting same issue.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.example.example">
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    
    
    
        <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
             calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
             In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
             additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
             FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
        <application
            android:label="Demo"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                android:exported="true"
                tools:node="merge"
                >
                <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                     the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                     while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                     to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
                <meta-data
                    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                    android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                    />
                <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                     Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                     screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                     gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                     Flutter's first frame. -->
                <meta-data
                    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                    android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
                    />
    
    
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                    android:value="demo"/>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
    
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
                 This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2"
                />
    
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What is your compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion   ? it should be  30 or 31

Comment: Its compileSdkVersion 31 and  targetSdkVersion 31

Comment: Can you please try without  tools:node="merge"

Comment: Yes I tried without it too. But still its gave same error. If I change the exported = false to true from the other libraries then It will start giving the errors to the build

Comment: Can you share that error

Comment: did u solve this issue??

Comment: yes @Alberto Acuna, I globally search all the exported value set manifest files. In between them I just change the value in the manifest file of firebase messaging. I set all android:exported="true" in the firebase messaging manifest

Comment: @AnkurShinde I just didnt find any other activity or receiver on my main manifest xml for add that export, but looks like still havin this error when try to upload the released apk to google play console :(

Comment: @Alberto Acuna Please search globally. Manifest files added in code from dependancy

Comment: I didnt, but another files manifest xml are in build file, should I modify it? @AnkurShinde

Comment: Yes, check for the firebase manifest file on priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I globally search all the exported value set manifest files. In between them I just change the value in manifest file of firebase messaging . I set all android:exported="true" in freebase messaging manifest

Comment: can you share your code to see where to add please ?

Comment: Open the project in the android module and search "android:exported" globally and change value to true

Answer (score 0):

Open up your android manifest using android studio and review the merged tab which is generated by other flutter packages for activities, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter.

add a android:exported="true" to any activities, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter.